# how to compare integer null values in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, integer, compare

how to compare integer null values in sql server

Answer (score 4):

Try to use

```
ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )
```

For example

```
select * from yourtable where isnull(yourcolumn,0)=0
```

When yourcolumn is null then isnull(yourcolumn,0) return 0

Comment: *When yourcolumn is null then isnull(yourcolumn,0) return 0* ... it also returns 0 when yourcolumn is 0 ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use IS NULL operator to look for NULL values.

```
WHERE ColName IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Varun
 You can use below functions to compare null values in the database.

```
ISNULL<br>
CASE<br>
IIF<br>
COALESCE
```